# auto update a jsp page when data is updated to database

Tags: jquery, jsp

I've a home.jsp  (displays data in tabular form) inside a form which opens a pop up window to update data (editUser.jsp).

```
<form method ="post" action="editUser.jsp"  onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
```

editUser.jsp has a form to update data

```
<form method="post" action="edit.jsp">

/*HTML FORM*/
```

after clicking on submit button it goes to edit.jsp page to update data to the database. *In the edit.jsp page contains only java code for updating data and nothing else*.

**Now i've to auto refresh home.jsp page after the data is inserted to database or when the submit button is pressed in editUser.jsp?** How can I do it?? Till now I've to manually refresh the page.**control flow of webpages**

> home.jsp ->editUser.jsp -> edit.jsp

```
$(function(){
               $("#submit").click(function(){

                  var a=$("#ID").val();
                  var b=$("#NAME").val();
                  var c=$("#PWD").val();
                  var datastring='ID=' + a + '&NAME=' + b+'&PWD='+c ;

                        $.ajax
                        ({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "edit.jsp",
                                data: datastring,
                                success: function(){

                                        window.close();
                                        window.location.href="home.jsp";


                                                        }
                        });
               });
            });
```

but this code is not working. How can I do it????

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in implementing something like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) for your use case. It's a Javascript MVVM framework with support for observable objects that automatically refresh on the client on server change. This way, you won't have to do a hard page refresh / reload.

Comment: Well, you can hook up your refresh logic via an event on your parent window, and trigger that event from the child (popup) window to effectively trigger a page refresh. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10767356/304588).

Comment: Basically you want your pop up window to tell your parent window that it's done doing whatever it needs to do --- you don't want AJAX for that. You can use AJAX in your parent window to check if the database has changed --- but that's precisely the workflow Knockout does for you.